# ¿Por qué no se cumple la condición (Firebase database)

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación, que en resumen, es un login. Se conecta a firebase database, obtiene los datos e inicia sesión. Pero tengo un problema, y es que a la hora de comprobar si el usuario ha iniciado (en el último if del método comprobarUsuario) la condición booleana siempre me devuelve false, a pesar de que los datos sí están bien escritos, ya que he puesto un intent y sí cambia de pantalla. Aquí está el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText miEditTextLoginNombre, miEditTextLoginPass;
    private Button miBotonLoginEntrar;
    private DatabaseReference alumnos;
    private DatabaseReference profesores;
    private DatabaseReference admins;
    private Admin admin;
    private Alumno alum;
    private Profesor profe;
    private String usuario, contra;
    private Snackbar sBar;
    boolean iniciado = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        miEditTextLoginNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLoginNombre);
        miEditTextLoginPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLoginPass);
        miBotonLoginEntrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginEntrar);

        alumnos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseReferences.ALUMNOS_REF);
        profesores = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseReferences.PROFESORES_REF);
        admins = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseReferences.ADMINS_REF);

        /**
         * Evento que se produce al pulsar el botón.
         */
        miBotonLoginEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                usuario = miEditTextLoginNombre.getText().toString();
                contra = miEditTextLoginPass.getText().toString();

                if(usuario.isEmpty() || contra.isEmpty()){
                    sBar = Snackbar.make(view, "Hay campos vacíos", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    sBar.show();
                }else{
                    comprobarUsuario();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Comprueba si el usuario se encuentra en la base de datos y nos cambia de pantalla.
     */
    public void comprobarUsuario(){
        alum = null;
        profe = null;
        admin = null;
        iniciado = false;

        alumnos.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snap.child("dni_alum").getValue().equals(usuario) && snap.child("clave").getValue().equals(contra)){
                        iniciado = true;
                        alum = snap.getValue(Alumno.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has iniciado sesión como User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        profesores.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snap.child("dni_profe").getValue().equals(usuario) && snap.child("clave").getValue().equals(contra)){
                        iniciado = true;
                        profe = snap.getValue(Profesor.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has iniciado sesión como User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        admins.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snap.child("dni").getValue().equals(usuario) && snap.child("clave").getValue().equals(contra)){
                        admin = snap.getValue(Admin.class);
                        iniciado = true;
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has iniciado sesión como Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        if(iniciado == false){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campos incrrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Paco ¿el `Toast` que dice: `Has iniciado sesión como User` se muestra? Después de él deberías poner un `break;` para que salga del bucle `for`, de lo contrario, si hay más valores seguirá comparando y cambiando el valor de `iniciado`
. De todos modos, la forma correcta de consultar a `Firebase` sería haciendo que te traiga un sólo registro coincidente, no varios.

Comment: Sí, he probado a ponerle un break; y sigue pasando lo mismo. El toast también se muestra y me lleva a la otra pantalla. Pero si pongo un break dentro del for, ¿no se saldría de él a la primera? Es decir, recogería solo información una vez y luego se saldría.

Comment: Sí, saldría. Yo entendí que lo que querías era comprobar si ese dato existía. La forma de comprobar es que lo encuentre al menos una vez ¿no?  Si ya lo encuentra una vez, ¿qué sentido tendría seguir recorriendo el `for`?  Aunque como ya te dije, lo correcto sería en este caso hacer una consulta que te traiga un solo dato filtrado por los criterios que quieres evaluar, no que traiga muchos datos para recorrerlos y encontrar uno entre varios. En `Firebase` hablan mucho de eso y advierten de tener cuidado a la hora de hacer las consultas, limitándolas lo más posible.

Comment: ¿Cómo podría hacer para que la consulta me traiga un solo dato? es que no lo entiendo. Yo estoy recorriendo toda la base de datos, pero solo me quedo con uno de todos esos resultados, creando un objeto a partir de esos datos.

Comment: @PacoPepe El problema es que el if no debe ir fuera del listener. La llamada a la base de datos es `asincrona`. Por lo tanto el if que esta fuera siempre se quedara con el valor inicial a menos que el valor llegue antes que el codigo en runtime lo cual es casi imposible. Ese if debe ir despues del for que esta en el `onDataChange`. Debes hacer algo como `task.whenAll` de las tareas. Te dejo un link de algo que deberias hacer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173569/only-load-layout-when-firebase-calls-are-complete?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Paco, si lo que quieres es verificar que el usuario `PacoPepe` existe en `Firebase` en vez de traer a todos los usuarios para comparar si existe, tendrías que hacer lo contrario, buscar, apuntando al nodo donde se encuentran los datos...

Comment: ...  Creas la referencia: `final DatabaseReference usersRef = database.getReference("users");`  Y ahora buscas con un método adecuado, por ejemplo: `usersRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("PacoPepe").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {  @Override public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) { System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey()); }

  // ...
});`
Estos ejemplos son de la [doc de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=es-419#section-queries).

Comment: He puesto el último if dentro del for del último onDataChange. Creo que no es muy elegante pero funciona.